# Nice inequality with a,b,c,d

Tags: inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**If $a,b,c,d>0$ with $a+b+c+d=1$, prove that $\displaystyle \frac{bcd}{a+2}+\frac{acd}{b+2}+\frac{abd}{c+2}+\frac{abc}{d+2} <\frac{1}{13}$.**

Comment: What is the source of this problem, OP?

Comment: And what are your attempts?

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{a+2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}bcd+\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{bcd}{a+2}-\frac{bcd}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}bcd-\sum_{cyc}\frac{abcd}{2(a+2)}<\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}bcd=$$
$$=\frac{abc+abd+acd+bcd}{2}=\frac{ab(c+d)+cd(a+b)}{2}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2(c+d)+\left(\frac{c+d}{2}\right)^2(a+b)}{2}=\frac{(a+b)(c+d)(a+b+c+d)}{8}=
$$
$$=\frac{(a+b)(c+d)}{8}\leq\frac{\left(\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}\right)^2}{8}=\frac{1}{32}<\frac{1}{13}$$

Comment: A nice proof, although probably better than OP's participation merits.

Comment: Nice. Though you can shorten the first step by observing: $\frac{bcd}{a+2} < \frac{bcd}{2}$ (since $a>0$). Thereby concluding $\sum_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{a+2} < \sum_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{2}$.

Comment: @Anurag A  You are right, but by my way we can get a best upper bound: $\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg my suggestion does not change anything in the remainder of your proof. So I'm not sure what you are referring to in terms of getting the best upper bound.

Comment: @Anurag A I mean that you are right. Indeed, the proof with $\frac{bcd}{a+2}<\frac{bcd}{2}$ is better, but this estimation will give a wrong inequality if we'll want to prove $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{a+2}\leq\frac{1}{36}$ with the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear and "good" bound solution, but get necessary:

$(1)$ Use Cauchy inequality $bcd\leqslant (\tfrac{b+c+d}{3})^3$; $acd\leqslant (\tfrac{a+c+d}{3})^3$; $abd\leqslant (\tfrac{a+b+d}{3})^3$; $abc\leqslant (\tfrac{a+b+c}{3})^3$

as $a+b+c+d=1$, we get $bcd\leqslant (\tfrac{1-a}{3})^3$; $acd\leqslant (\tfrac{1-b}{3})^3$; $abd\leqslant (\tfrac{1-c}{3})^3$; $abc\leqslant (\tfrac{1-d}{3})^3$

So, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{a+2} \leqslant\tfrac{(1-a)^3}{27(a+2)}+\tfrac{(1-b)^3}{27(b+2)}+\tfrac{(1-c)^3}{27(c+2)}+\tfrac{(1-d)^3}{27(d+2)}$$

Then, as  $0<a,b,c,d<1$ we can take value at zero in the right side inequality addends for further inequality estimation, because numerator increases and denominator decreases as $a,b,c,d$ approach to $0$.

Finally, we have: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{bcd}{a+2} \leqslant\tfrac{(1-a)^3}{27(a+2)}+\tfrac{(1-b)^3}{27(b+2)}+\tfrac{(1-c)^3}{27(c+2)}+\tfrac{(1-d)^3}{27(d+2)}<\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}=\frac{1}{13.5}<\frac{1}{13}$$